# Multi-Threaded Pipelined Game Engine Data Synchronization Questions

Tags: architecture, multithreading

Let's say I'm setting up a worker pool based game engine with pipelining. Let's say I have 4 stages in my pipeline as such:

- Stage 1: Physics
- Stage 2: AI/Input
- Stage 3: Game Logic
- Stage 4: Rendering

Now let's say that the physics detects a collision between a bullet and a character in stage 1. Two frames later the game logic may choose to remove that bullet from the simulation, however none of the other copies of the data for the other pipeline stages will get this information. How is this sort of thing and other things like it get handled? Do you generally make changes like this to every pipeline stage's data at the end of a frame?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, one way to deal with this is to buffer up the events generated by each stage and then subsequent stages can iterate over those event queues.  So the physics stage can iterate over the events generated by the AI stage and apply their results, which the game logic and rendering stages would also do.

Another option is to simply not use multiple copies of data but rather to use a fork-and-join worker system where each system works in series but the systems themselves divide their work between the available cores, though that is obviously not an answer to your question.

Update: forgot to link the usual blog post for event systems in data-oriented-driven architectures: http://bitsquid.blogspot.com/2009/12/events.html

Comment: I'm actually doing both. I'm using TBB with a pipeline and when I can, I dispatch multiple workers to do work in any given pipeline as well. My goal is to have it scale to many more cores than I currently have but still run OK on the 4 in my machine. Thanks for the tip though, time to write an event system. :)